# Unity & Oculus Quest: Lightweight Render Pipeline (LWRP) distorts right eye

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I am currently trying to get my project in Oculus Quest working using the Lightweight Render Pipeline. I am using VRTK4 and UnityXRCameraRig for my VR cam.

However, since I got the render pipeline the right eye is distorted (has a different setting), and I cannot change it's setting. Here are the settings:

***LWRP:***

[image]

***HeadAnchor (UnityXRCameraRig):***

[image]

***Virtual Reality Settings:***

[image]

Any idea how to work around this issue using the UnityXRCameraRig prefab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading to the newest version of Unity (2019.3.2f1)